# FCM - Send a notification to iOS device using expo (React native)

Tags: ios, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging, expo

I'm unable to send push notification to an iOS app created with [Expo.io](https://expo.io/).

There's not a clear doc on how to do so so here are my trials and things I've done :

- First I've created my firebase project and [setup it for iOS](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client)
- I've also read [this -not that complete- guide](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications-custom/) to setup the POST call to FCM server
- I've added my APN push notification key to my firebase project

[image: firebase project with APN keys]

And before calling this endpoint programatically I'm trying to get it working (as I did in less than 1h for android) with POSTMAN

Here is what I'm calling :

method: POST

url : https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send

body :

```
{
  "to": "token (read about it at the end of the post",
  "priority": "high",
  "data": {
    "experienceId": "@expoAccount/projectSlug",
    "title": "Hello there",
    "message": "General kenobi",
    "content_available": true
  },
    "content_available": true
}
```

I've tested a lot of body different structures (with / whithout "content_available" key or with "notification" object ... Because all body structures are diffent from
[all](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44035518/firebase-fcm-error-invalidregistration)
[the](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67363532/ios-fcm-notification-send-push-notification-to-multiple-users-at-once)
[questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57463903/having-trouble-with-push-notifications-to-ios-devices-with-fcm)
[or docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/http-server-ref)
[I've](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041829/using-fcm-token-obtained-via-batchimport-ios)
[read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67051941/fcm-throwing-invalid-argument-for-ios-notifications)
[so far](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/blob/master/trouble-shooting.md)

So I'm not sur of the body I must send ... But If the notification works on Android it should work on iOS or I don't see the point of FCM ...

## Talking about the token used for iOS

For iOS the token I'm getting from `Notifications.getDevicePushTokenAsync()` ([expo doc](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications-custom/)) isn't a valid FCM token because somehow it "connects" to some sandbox or whatever Apple call that <s>shit</s> behaviour.

Without [this thread](https://github.com/zo0r/react-native-push-notification/issues/1251) I would be lost in the void... So the token I use is the one I get after "transforming" the sandbox token to a "true" one calling the google api : https://iid.googleapis.com/iid/v1:batchImport

I'm sometimes facing some strange behaviour, especially when sending with the key `"content_available": true` : The token seems to be "forced uneregistred".

Why I'm saying this ? Because on the first call the result is : `"results": [{ "error": "InvalidRegistration" }],` and all the next calls answers are : `"results": [{ "error": "NotRegistered" }],`

and the batchImport generate a new token when called with the "sandboxToken" which doesn't change when I receive some success return (depending on that body structure) : `"results": [{"message_id": "0:1632152120739230%37bf04f1f9fd7ecd"}],`

Note: I've got some successfull return but no notification on the i-phone at all.

Comment: From my experience using Expo, setting up notifications for iOS doesn't need FCM, I use FCM for android and non-expo projects. I run this cmd: expo build:ios -t archive and then let expo manage everything... Then I enable push notifications on app developer account. Then I test using expo notification tool. Android is a different story

Answer (score 4):

Currently FCM for iOS Apps is not supported on Expo Apps.

"Note that FCM is not currently available for Expo iOS apps." -> https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/using-fcm/

For iOS you have 2 options so far:

1. Call APNs, the info is on the [link](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications-custom/#apns-server) you pointed out.
2. [Use Expo push notifications service](https://docs.expo.dev/push-notifications/sending-notifications/)

Answer (score 0):

You can use in this case expo [eas build](https://docs.expo.dev/build/introduction/) to build ios though you are using bare workflow project then eas will take care aboute all required configurations to run expo push notifications on ios

Answer (score 0):

From what I can understand, expo handles notifications for both IOS and Android by delivering IOS notifications through Apples APNs (Apple Push Notification service), and android via FCM (Firebase Cloud Messaging).

So when using expo to `getDevicePushTokenAsync`, the type of token you get back depends on device. If running an android device you'll get a token that can be used directly within the firebase console to send a test message, but if using an apple device the native token you get can only be used with the apple push server. So that is why device push tokens generated from expo can't be used directly with FCM.

To make things more confusing, FCM can still send messages to IOS devices, via some mapping/magic that firebase cloud mesaging calls [swizzling](https://firebase.google.com/docs/cloud-messaging/ios/client#method_swizzling_in), however if wanting to use this you'd likely have to use a different native plugin,e.g. [react-native-firebase](https://rnfirebase.io/messaging/usage), or manually migrate the apns tokens via the google [create_registration_tokens_for_apns_tokens](https://developers.google.com/instance-id/reference/server#) api